# PysimpleGUI can't read inputFields in the sg.WIN_CLOSED event

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to save the path and the filename from the input fields with the keys -PATH- and -FILENAME- when I close the app so if I change the filename and the path it will be saved in a text file and loaded on the next start. However when I try to read the inputText '-FILENAME-' in the sg.WIN_CLOSED event i get 'NoneType' object is not subscribable TypeError, but if i use the same way x = values['-FILENAME-'] in the -SAVE AS- event it works just fine and prints the filename in the console

Any help is appreciated!

```
#create Window
window = sg.Window('Digispark BADUSB Script Creator', layout, size=(1500, 500))

#Eventloop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == 'EXIT' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        print(values['-PATH-'])
        break

        
    if event == '-SAVEAS-':
        codeText = values['textbox']
        completeText = textBegin + codeText +textEnd
        filename = values['-FILENAME-']
        path = values['-PATH-']
        if len(filename) == 0 or len(path) == 0:
            errorPopup('Filename or Path empty! Go to SETTINGS-TAB!')
        else:
            try:
                destination = path + filename
                file1 = open(destination, 'w')
                file1.write(completeText)
                file1.close()
            except:
                errorPopup("Invalid Path! Change Settings")
 
window.close()
```

Comment: Try to post minimum required code to demonstrate your issue (standalone runnable as well when possible).  The benefit of this is that 1: this will often lead you to finding and fixing your own bug, 2: makes it much easier for SO readers to identify issues in your code and potentially run it for themselves.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too long to read it.

When event window close button clicked, it is defined to destroy the window and you may or will get nothing from that window. Most of time, the value of `values` will be `None`, so you cannot read the content of `sg.Input` element from it.

Try to use option `enable_close_attempted_event=True` in `sg.Window` if you want to do something before window closed, then it will not destroy the window first.

Demo code as following,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
font = ('Arial', 10)

defaultPath     = "Here's your default path"
defaultFilename = "Here's your default filanme"

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Path:',     size=(10,1)), sg.InputText(defaultPath,     key='-PATH-')],
    [sg.Text('Filename:', size=(10,1)), sg.InputText(defaultFilename, key='-FILENAME-')]
]

window = sg.Window('Test1', layout, resizable=True, finalize=True, enable_close_attempted_event=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
        print(values['-PATH-'])
        print(values['-FILENAME-'])
        break

window.close()
```